# Обработка команд и разделение взаимодействий DISCORD.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-api

У меня есть бот, у которого большое количество команд. Все команды и взаимодействия построены на async - await

`async execute(client, interaction)(в самой команде)` и `async execute(interaction, client) (в взаимодействии команды. при нажатии на кнопку и т.п)` . Есть фаил **interactionCreate.js** , в котором обрабатываются команды

```
async execute(interaction, client) {
if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
            if (interaction.user.bot) return;
            const command = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!command) {
                interaction.reply({
                    ephemeral: true,
                    content: "This Command is outdated!"
                });
            };
            try {
                command.execute(client, interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`${color.bold.red(`[INTERACTION > CREATE SLASH : ERROR]`)}` + `${error}.`.bgRed);
            }
        };
        if (interaction.isContextMenuCommand()) {
            if (interaction.user.bot) return;
            const context = client.slashCommands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!context) {
                interaction.reply({
                    ephemeral: true,
                    context: "This command is outdated!"
                });
            };
            try {
                context.execute(client, interaction);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`${color.bold.red(`[INTERACTION > CREATE CONTEXT : ERROR]`)}` + `${error}.`.bgRed);
            }
        };
};
```

Там же ниже происходит взаимодействие всех кнопок `if(interaction.isButton() {<code>}`, `if(interaction.isStringSelectMenu() {<code>}` и так далее. Мой знакомый сказал, что не правильно делать это в одном файле, ведь при прописывании любой из моих команд будет выполняться `execute` всех моих команд. Он сказал, что нужно разделить взаимодействие кнопок, селект менюшек и т.п. Есть одно но. Я не понимаю, что это значит, а он внятно объяснить не может. Может ли кто-нибудь мне помочь?

*Примечание: я начинающий программист*